# Uploading file to a REST api server using Android HTTP client

Tags: android, rest, httpclient

I am using a dummy rest API server called [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server). I wrote an android app which is able to make POSt request to the server, server returns an expected 201 as well.

I am not very familiar with REST api. I want to send a File from my device

```
     public void run() {
                    Logger.d("reponse","inside thread");

                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(TunnelView.this);
                    String url = "http://some_server:3000/comments";
                    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
                    HttpResponse response = null;
                    post.setEntity(new FileEntity(new File("/root/sdcard/Download/File.txt"),"application/octect-stream"));
                    try
                    {
                        response = client.execute(post);
                        String res = response.getEntity().getContent().toString();
                        Logger.d("response", res);




                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Every time I do a post, a new Id is added under the Comments array on my json file located on the rest API server.

```
  "comments": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "body": "some comment",
  "postId": 1
},
{
  "id": 2
},]
```

I am not sure how to change my android code or the REST API Post URl so I can send the whole text file content and it gets posted on the json file on the server.

Comment: `localhost` ? Is the server on the Android device too?

Comment: Other than the `localhost` problem, how to you know that the server supports file upload?

Comment: It's not localhost, updated the code. Can someone explain the downvote? I got to agree with the author here : https://medium.com/@johnslegers/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d#.cb8mr39l6

Comment: Dont spend your time on this server. If you can read then you see that file upload is not supported.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Can you please point me in the right direction, any generic approach on how to upload a file to the rest API server using the HTTP client ?

Comment: Every day this question is posted on stackoverflow. So just read some pages with tag android. Or google for it.

Comment: Actually the solution posted by Arpit works flawlessly, I tweaked it a little and was able to send the file in JSON format to the same server. Thanks again for all your help. I request all the experienced coders to give a chance to newbies and don't rush to those -1s :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this out

```
    public static JSONObject postFile(String url,String filePath,int id){
    String result="";
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    File file = new File(filePath);
    MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
    StringBody stringBody= null;
    JSONObject responseObject=null;
    try {
        stringBody = new StringBody(id+"");
        mpEntity.addPart("file", cbFile);
        mpEntity.addPart("id",stringBody);
        httpPost.setEntity(mpEntity);
        System.out.println("executing request " + httpPost.getRequestLine());
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
        result=resEntity.toString();
        responseObject=new JSONObject(result);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return responseObject;
}
```

this code works perfectly, use this and if you find any difficulty, do comment.

```
 Happy coding!!
```

Comment: Thanks Arpit, I tweaked your code a bit and it able to send my file now.